# bonigarcia webdrivermanager firefox browser issue

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have used the below dependency to open the browser with the following command,

**chrome :**

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**firefox :**

```
 WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().arch64().setup();
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

**Dependency  :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

For the Chrome browser it is working. but for firefox i getting some issues,

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.931 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] Test(com.Googlesearch.automation.DemoforGoogle)  Time elapsed: 4.397 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0Q6C6CP', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace:
        at com.Googlesearch.automation.DemoforGoogle.CheckGooglechrome(DemoforGoogle.java:19)
        at com.Googlesearch.automation.DemoforGoogle.Test(DemoforGoogle.java:35)

[ERROR] Test1(com.Googlesearch.automation.DemoforGoogle)  Time elapsed: 1.873 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0Q6C6CP', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace:
        at com.Googlesearch.automation.DemoforGoogle.CheckGooglechrome(DemoforGoogle.java:19)
        at com.Googlesearch.automation.DemoforGoogle.Test1(DemoforGoogle.java:40)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   DemoforGoogle.Test:35->CheckGooglechrome:19 » SessionNotCreated Unable to find...
[ERROR]   DemoforGoogle.Test1:40->CheckGooglechrome:19 » SessionNotCreated Unable to fin...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.193 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-25T19:43:17+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project com.Googlesearch.automation: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Hp\workspace\com.Googlesearch.automation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.Google.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.Googlesearch.automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
<suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


</dependencies>

  <build>
  <plugins>

  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>

    <configuration>

    <suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>

  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please help me, want i need to change in code or dependency for firefox browser

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am facing similar 1.

Comment: I resolved the issue by updating the browser, or pass specific webdriver gecko version that supports the FF current version in your example: machine.WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().driverVersion("0.30.0").setup();